# React js navigator implemented in web app

Tags: meteor, reactjs

React Native contains the component `<Navigator />` which has several functions to manage scenes such as `pop`, `push` (and support swiping)

I want to implement the same features in web app / cordova app / browser using react js (run using Meteor). Are there similar built-in functions/components in react js? I have looked through the docs and couldn't find any.

Comment: I doubt no. However if you have design the UI for navigation, you can use : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ , which is backed up by Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

The navigator push/pop functionality can be mimicked by using react-router (see https://github.com/reactjs/react-router). The hashHistory module has methods like push and pop.

Bootstrap will provide you with some UI as Ant has commented; for swiping you could use JQuery Mobile.

```
$("#myComponent").on("swipe", function(e) {
   console.log(e)
});
```

Just don't expect the native feel with this :)